# MySQL execute statement return NoneType

Tags: python, mysql, sum, nonetype

I have a txt file that has a list of baby names ranked with how many babies were born with that name. format (rank, boy name, number, percent, girl name, number, and percent) 
example: `1  Michael  462085  2.2506  Jessica  302962  1.5436`. I have done code to parse this into an array and places each value into a separate column. I want to sum all the boys_number to find the total number of boys born. The sql statement I use works in the sql console but python keeps returning "None." Should I make a separate function, or is this a quick fix. The code that finds the sum is at the bottom

```
import mysql.connector
from decimal import Decimal


db = mysql.connector.connect(
     host = "localhost",
     user="root",
     passwd = "",
     database = "Final"
     )

cur = db.cursor()

Boys_born = 50       
babies_born = 0
index = 0
#opens txt file and splits each value and plugs into database
with open("babynames.txt") as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        row = []
        stripped_line = line.strip()
        row = stripped_line.split()



        RANK = row[0]
        BOY_NAME = row[1]
        BOY_NUMBER = int(row[2])
        BOY_PERCENT = Decimal(row[3])
        GIRL_NAME = row[4]
        GIRL_NUMBER = int(row[5])
        GIRL_PERCENT = Decimal(row[6])

#dont worry about this if statement
        if babies_born >= 16079293.5:
            boy = row[1]
            girl = row[4]

        sql1 = "INSERT INTO Boy_names (RANK, BOY_NAME, BOY_NUMBER, BOY_PERCENT) VALUES (%s, 
%s, %s, %s)"
    val1 = (RANK, BOY_NAME, BOY_NUMBER, BOY_PERCENT)

    cur.execute(sql1, val1)
    db.commit()

    sql2 = "INSERT INTO Girl_names (RANK, GIRL_NAME, GIRL_NUMBER, GIRL_PERCENT) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)"
    val2 = (RANK, GIRL_NAME, GIRL_NUMBER, GIRL_PERCENT)

    cur.execute(sql2, val2)
    db.commit()

Boy_total = cur.execute("SELECT SUM(BOY_NUMBER) FROM Boy_names")
print(Boy_total)
for i in cur.fetchall():
    print(i)
```

Comment: Yeah, `cur.execute()` returns `None`. That's normal behavior. Data is accessed through things like `fetchall()` that you are already using. I don't see any problems here.